# Most efficient way to check alternate entries in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an int array of size 10000, it is composed of only 1's and 0's.When I convert this to a string, it looks like this

```
String str="101010101010101010101001010101010101011110000000000001101010101101......"
```

My task is to check whether this array has alternate entries or not.

I tried it like this:

```
       Case 1:                                           Case 2:
//when str=010101010.....                         //when str=101010101.....
boolean cha =true;                                boolean ch=true;
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)                              for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{                                                 {
    if(j%2==0)                                         if(j%2==1)
    {                                                  {
       if(arr[j]==1)                                       if(arr[j]==0)
          cha=false;                                           cha=true;
    }                                                   }
    if(j%2==1)                                         if(j%2==0)
    {                                                   {
        if(arr[j]==0)                                       if(arr[j]==1)
            cha=false;                                           ch=false;
    }                                                    }
    if(cha==false)                                     if(ch==false) 
        break;                                              break;
}                                                  }

if(cha==true)                                     if(ch==true)
     System.out.println("YES");                   System.out.println("YES");
```

Is there any better way than just looping through the whole array, comparing each and every term and then, breaking when not found as alternate?

Comment: What you have doesn't make much sense. You set `cha=false` regardless of whether `j%2` is 1 or 0. In both cases.

Comment: It's also not clear where the string part comes in, seeing as you don't use that (or the array) in your loop...#

Comment: i just wanted to show how my array looks thats why I used it @JonSkeet

Comment: but the given code does not make any sense, what is that supposed to be, you are just iterating over n and do nothing with it except checking it %.

Comment: @kunjalrupala. Your code does not check the elements of the array, only the indices.

Comment: oops!! am soo sry I just forgot to mention a line of code there wait i ll edit it@khelwood

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the question that everybody is giving a downvote??

Comment: Well, 1) for some reason you've decided to put code side by side, despite that making it invalid code; 2) you initially posted garbage code that made no sense whatsoever; 3) you haven't explained your problem clearly enough; 4) you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet I am very new to stack overflow .So a small request to you, can you please tell me what should i edit in my problem so that i can know how to post a question...

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ thoroughly - and ask yourself whether posting your code in two columns is really as helpful as it can be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
String pattern = "^(10)+1{0,1}$|^(01)+0{0,1}$";
String s1 = "01010101";
String s2 = "101010101";
String s3 = "11001111";
s1.matches(pattern); // return true
s2.matches(pattern); // return true
s3.matches(pattern); // return false
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist, She said that he converts it to a string, so use the string to do this

Comment: No, OP converts it to a string to show us what it looks like.

Comment: @kunjalrupala. Apologies. No disrespect intended.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, *"When I convert this to a string, it looks like this..."* So she has the string representation, this code can work

Comment: @ThibautB. Fair enough. Objection rescinded.

Comment: @kunjalrupala, If you can use your string representation of your array, just write ```str.matches("(01|10)+")``` and you have your boolean answer

Comment: @kunjalrupala, with this regex ```"^(10)+1{0,1}$|^(01)+0{0,1}$"``` it should work, I edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in a "streamy" Java 8 solution:

```
int[] input =  ..... // your array

// create an IntStream with the values of the input array at the even indices ...
// ... then get the unique elements and count how many you have
long countEven = IntStream.range(0, input.length)
                    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).map(i -> input[i]).distinct().count();
// do the same for the uneven indices
long countUneven = IntStream.range(0, input.length)
                    .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0).map(i -> input[i]).distinct().count();
// if the even/uneven indices contain 1 unique element each, 
// ... the array contains alternating numbers
if (countEven == 1L && countUneven == 1L) System.out.println("alternating 1s and 0s!");
```

Comment: A good approach, especially as it keeps the `int[]` as stated. I do think a bit of explanation as to how it works would be helpful. Also, perhaps a statement about the efficiency of this approach.

Comment: I have added a bit of explanation. Hard to say something about the performance. If the string-representation of the array is already there, the solution with `String#matches` seriously outperforms this solution. If creating the string is taken into account it will depend on the method used to go from `int[]` to `String`, my method will start to catch up or do even better when the array gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would probably be to verify all the elements against the first two:

```
// Replace this with a better test if you can have something other than 0 and 1
if(arr[0] + arr[1] != 1) {
    cha = false;
} else {
    for(int i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != arr[i % 2]) {
            cha = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`cha` will be set to `false` if an even element is not equal to whatever is in `arr[0]` because `i % 2` will always be zero for even elements. Same goes for odd elements and `arr[1]`.